# Change tenant id runtime

Tags: angular, firebase, google-identity

I'm using firebase in combination with google identity platform with multi-tenancy.
The tenant id is provided as injection token by angularfire, and can be set in the providers section of a module.

But i want to update this value based on the tenant the user selects in the login screen.
I cant seem to find the correct way of doing that.

Anyone knows if that's possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
firebase.auth().tenantId = 'other-tenant-id'
```